# clusplot - showing variables

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, pca

I would like to add to a `clusplot` plot the variables used for pca as arrows. I am not sure that a way has been implemented (I can't find anything in the documentation).

I have produced a clusplot that looks like this:

[image: clusters produced with clusplot]

With the package `princomp` I can independently plot the observations in an analogous space of representation, with the variables (columns) as arrows:

[image]

Is there a way to do the two things at the same time, by showing the clusters and the variables of pca on the same diagram?

Comment: This question may be better suited at Cross Validated.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to to the same thing as OP today and ended up putting pieces from `clusplot` and `biplot` together. This is the result which may be useful if you want to do the same thing:

```
clusplot2 <- function(dat, clustering, ...) {
    clusplot(dat, clustering, ...)

    ##  this is from clusplot.default
    pca <- princomp(dat, scores = TRUE, cor = (ncol(dat) != 2))

    ##  this is (adapted) from biplot.princomp 
    directions <- t(t(pca$loadings[, 1:2]) * pca$sdev[1:2]) * sqrt(pca$n.obs)

    ##  all below is (adapted) from biplot.default
    unsigned.range <- function(x) c(-abs(min(x, na.rm = TRUE)), 
                                    abs(max(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
    x <- predict(pca)[, 1:2]
    y <- directions
    rangx1 <- unsigned.range(x[, 1L])
    rangx2 <- unsigned.range(x[, 2L])
    rangy1 <- unsigned.range(y[, 1L])
    rangy2 <- unsigned.range(y[, 2L])
    xlim <- ylim <- rangx1 <- rangx2 <- range(rangx1, rangx2)
    ratio <- max(rangy1/rangx1, rangy2/rangx2)
    par(new = T)
    col <- par("col")
    if (!is.numeric(col)) 
        col <- match(col, palette(), nomatch = 1L)
    col <- c(col, col + 1L)
    cex <- rep(par("cex"), 2)
    plot(y, axes = FALSE, type = "n", xlim = xlim * ratio, ylim = ylim * 
             ratio, xlab = "", ylab = "", col = col[1L])
    axis(3, col = col[2L])
    axis(4, col = col[2L])
    box(col = col[1L])
    text(y, labels = names(dat), cex = cex[2L], col = col[2L])
    arrows(0, 0, y[, 1L] * 0.8, y[, 2L] * 0.8, col = col[2L], 
           length = 0.1)
}

############################################################

library(cluster)

dat <- iris[, 1:4]

clus <- pam(dat, k = 3)
clusplot2(dat, clus$clustering, main = "Test")
```

Of course there is much room for improvement (as this is just copied together) but I think anyone can easily adapt it if needed.

If you wonder why the arrows (loadings * sdev) are scaled with 0.8 * sqrt(n): I have absolutely no idea. I would have plotted loadings * sdev which should resemble the correlation between the principal components and the variables but this is how `biplot` does it.

Anyway, this should produce the same arrows as `biplot.princomp` and use the same pca as `clusplot` which was the primary goal for me.